# Jasper Server "fusion component not supported" rendering a PDF

Tags: jasperserver, visualize

I have several reports which have been integrated into a dashboard web app.  On several of the reports we use the "Widgets Pro" angular gauge component.  This renders and displays fine with visualize.js.  The user would like to be able to export some of these as PDF documents.  It renders fine if I export to PDF from within TIBCO jasper studio, but when I deploy it jaspersoft-pro and attempt to export it as a PDF or a DOCX file from the server the component does not render and the error message "[Fusion Component Not Supported]" is left in its place.

I'm not really sure where to start with this.  I assume some components or libraries need to be added to our server.

A couple other details to mention:  The workstation on which I develop is Windows.  The server is Linux based.  We are running TIBCO jasperserver 7.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the local crew ended up figuring this out.

Turns out that PhantomJS needed to be updated and configured on the jaspersoft-pro server, to 2.1.1 in our case.

More specific steps:

1. Download PhantomJS 2.1.1 from official website and extract to an appropriate spot on your system (like /usr/local/phantomjs).
2. Edit $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/jasperserver-pro/WEB-INF/js.config.properties and set "phantomjs.binary=/usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs"
3. Edit $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/jasperserver-pro/WEB-INF/classes/jasperreports.properties and set "net.sf.jasperreports.phantomjs.executable.path=/usr/local/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs"